# Capturar fecha con js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, crud

Esty creando una pagina para reservar en un restaurante. Estoy en la parte de actualizar una reserva y tengo hecha una ventana emergente que recoge los datos de la reserva indentificada por el id.

Quiero mostrar la fecha cuando quiero editar una reserva, pero me sale el campo vacio?

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){

fila = $(this).closest("tr");
id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
nom = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
apellidos = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
email = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
telefon = fila.find('td:eq(4)').text();
persones = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(5)').text());
data = Date(fila.find('td:eq(6)').text());
hora = fila.find('td:eq(7)').text();

$("#nom").val(nom);
$("#apellidos").val(apellidos);
$("#email").val(email);
$("#telefon").val(telefon);
$("#persones").val(persones);
$("#data").val(data);
$("#hora").val(hora);
opcion = 2; //editar

$(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#4e73df");
$(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
$(".modal-title").text("Editar Persona");            
$("#modalCRUD").modal("show");    
});
```

Adjunto captura pantalla como veo el resultado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que intentes colocar una fecha con un formato diferente al que es aceptador por el input. [Mira la nota acerca del valor del input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

Asegurate que $("#data").val() reciba la fecha en formato **aaaa-mm-dd**.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon Luis. Como lo puedo solucionar esto, para poder ver el campo de la fecha?

Comment: Puedes hacer un console.log(data) para ver como recibes la fecha en tu variable data.
Y para formatear al formato que necesitas mira aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Con esta linea de codigo he descubierto que me devuelve el campo correctamente dia/mes/año.

data = fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();

Ahora creo que no sigue viendo la respuesta porque esta en formato tipo string? Tengo que transformar a typo date?

Comment: Recuerda que para agregar información adicional siempre puedes [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/573225/edit) tu pregunta. ;)